# Where does "Your Kitten of Death awaits" come from?

Tags: windows, sbcl

If you run SBCL (at least on Windows, I use CLISP at home), you get the message, "Your Kitten of Death awaits."  I suspect that this has something to do with some form of inside joke (like Super Cow Powers).  I've tried Googling and I have found nothing particularly useful (I suppose that it is mentioned elsewhere on the 'net is of some, if not much, use).

If this seems more of a SuperUser or ServerFault question, please let me know and I will ask on their forums instead.

---

#### UPDATE:

It seems that the origin of this quote is from [a commit](http://sbcl.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/sbcl/sbcl/src/runtime/runtime.c?r1=1.53&r2=1.54) by Christopher Rhodes to version 1.54 of the original source (thanks to [Daniel A. White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white) for finding the fild name).  I'm not sure if that will prove useful, but it is an additional avenue to approach this query.

Comment: The entire StackExchange series of sites no longer has any sense of humor. Give up.

Comment: @Mark Ransom I'm not really trying to being funny here.  I genuinely want to know (and I will likely be bothered by it until I have a solution).  I find "Hacker Lore" to be fascinating and that it should be propagated whenever possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a diff that has it, but its been removed in this patch.

http://www.peerweb.nl/sbcl/sbcl-1.0.14.10-windows.patch

Comment: I don't think he's asking where it comes from in the code, but where the idea for that phrase came from (like is it a movie or book quote or did the SBCL developer have a particularly vicious little pet).

Comment: That is definitely interesting, but I am really wondering about the viciousness of pets in SBCL community. (If I continue using it, will I need to worry that my Cocker Spaniel will turn into an angry tabby?)

Comment: But I will give you a +1 for a reference to the file it was created in.  Now all I need to do is wade through however many thousand commits to figure out who added it originally and then stalk them to figure out this line of output.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an interesting discussion on this very topic:
http://www.bitchx.com/log/lisp-f/lisp-f-02-Feb-2010/lisp-f-02-Feb-2010-00.php

They seem to suggest it comes from one of the following:

- The nursing home cat that could detect when someone was going to die (Recent [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1401323235) written about the "Grim Reapurr")
- The long comic series by Sluggy Freelance about satanic kittens (starts [here](http://www.sluggy.com/comics/archives/daily/000626), ends [here](http://www.sluggy.com/comics/archives/daily/000813))
- Or is inspired by Death's kitten(s) in the Discworld series by Terry Pratchett (Image [here](http://www.paulkidby.com/tshirts/deathwithkitten-1.htm))

Comment: All of those would definitely be sources of hacker lore...

Comment: Ah... Sluggy.  "Is it not nifty?"